# Can one house have different cable and internet?

Tags: wireless-networking, internet

The WIFI signal from my houses cable/internet provider (Optimum Online/Altice) will not reach my bedroom no matter what brand of extender I've used.

With cost not a problem, can I call Verizon and have then do a new install for just internet and have the main Router in my bedroom while the rest of the house keeps their current service?

I'm not sure if this is possible due to where the internet has to be connected and all that, I'm not tech savvy in that respect. Thanks! Altice has said they cannot do the install and supply another main box in the same house but I dont know if they just won't, or if it cant be done.

Comment: This would be up to the provider's policy.  Have you called Verizon to ask them if you can even become a customer?

Comment: You are not under any obligation to use the ISP wireless. None. You can have the Internet installed wherever you wish in your home but there may be cable up the wall. Then they may ask where the splitter (Cable TV / Internet splitter) should be.

Comment: A second ISP is an extreme/unnecessary solution to your simple problem.  *"With cost not a problem..."* -- Then hire someone to extend the cable signal to another location in the house so that the wireless router can provide the coverage you want.  Or try powerline Ethernet.  The typical ISP offers "free" installation, but that is at its convenience, i.e. their equipment will be located at the easiest-access & closest-to-the street point in your house/home.

Comment: Maybe call the manufacturer of wifi extenders to see what solutions they suggest?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to solve the wrong problem. Technically you can have 2 connections + 2 routers and have them work (just use different SSIDs/AP names and frequencies), but in this case "anything an ISP can do you can do too".

The obvious answer would be to get someone in to run a cable from the router to the other side of the house and plug in an AP there.

That said  have you explored using Ethernet over powerline to create a virtual Ethernet connection between the locations? (Performance is very dependent on your electrical wiring but often its a good solution.)

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to have a second WiFi point at the other end of your house. What you need to do is:

1. Go buy a 100ft CAT6 cable, see Amazon or similar.
2. Plug one end of your cable into the back of your existing WiFi router (there should be 4).
3. Feed your cable to the other end of your house. Think of a way to do this neatly or ask someone who is handy to help. You could go through a wall to the outside and then around the outside walls and back in at the other end. Or up into the roof and then along in there and down at the other end. Or behind base-boards and through walls until you get to the other end.
4. Buy a WiFi router (if you don't already have a spare one one). The more you pay the better the signal though something like a $100 AX1800 is fine. Plug this router in where your cable is. Set up the WiFi or use the default on the back of the router. Job done.

Similarly, if your house is less than say 3000sqft. You could do this:

1. Buy a 50ft CAT6 cable.
2. Plug one end of your cable into the back of your existing WiFi router.
3. Go up into the roof and into your loft, you want the cable to be in the middle of your house in the loft.
4. Buy a $200+ WiFi Router like an AX5400 or above (very strong signal).
5. Plug this router in where your cable is, middle of your loft. Set up the WiFi or use the default on the back of the router. Job done.

The reason the second one works is that the WiFi signal on a router goes out and down, hence into the house rooms below. Also it being a more expensive model the signal will go further.

Note: Connect to the 2.4Ghz signals and try those over the 5Ghz, the  2.4's also go further. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Where you write "Buy a WiFi router (if you don't already have a spare one one). The more you pay the better the signal though something like a $100 AX1800 is fine. Plug this router in where your cable is. " <-- Do you mean he sets the second router up as just a wireless access point?

Comment: I am trying to keep it simple with no need to do admin things like login and change settings on the router. So:

As soon as you plug in the second router, connected to the first WiFi router. The second router will be given an IP from the first routers DHCP. And it will be acting as a separate network with it's own WiFi (and DHCP, SSID, etc). 

But yes if you're more tech savvy. You can login to the new router and set it up as an access point on the same network (turn off DHCP, etc). However I think from the question, Sal would find this part confusing and end of the day doesn't need it.

Comment: Couldn't that lead to network problems though, two routers trying to do DHCP.  Two routers having  different subnets. And I suppose even that they won't be able to communicate if each is on a different subnet.(which preconfigured/by default, they might be)  Also, he could actually buy a wireless access point, I have a wireless access point somewhere, made by TP-Link.